# Cognitive Services : Language Understanding (LUIS) - phrase list features allowed per model cannot exceed the limit of 10

Tags: azure, azure-language-understanding, azure-cognitive-services

I was trying to create phrase lists to my LUIS model, to further enhance its capabilities. But I bumped in to this error when trying to create my 11th phrase list.

image link: https://clip2net.com/s/44yQ1vQ

> Bad Argument: The phrase list features allowed per model cannot exceed the limit of 10

But in their website in [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-boundaries), it said the limit is 500. Am I missing something here or is this something of a bad documentation.

Your suggestions and insights are much welcome.

Answer (score 1):

The error is correct, From the [**docs**](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure///////cognitive-services/luis/luis-boundaries)

> Maximum number of models that can be used as a descriptor (feature) to
>   a specific model to be 10 models. The maximum number of phrase lists
>   used as a descriptor (feature) for a specific model to be 10 phrase
>   lists.

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue that even though the limit on phraselists is 500 it gives an error after 10.This error is not because of the number of limits, it is because of the number of GLOBAL lists here.
GLOBAL lists act as descriptors for all models and if you have 10 global lists you exceed the limitation on the number of descriptors for a single model.

> Maximum number of models that can be used as a descriptor (feature) to a specific model to be 10 models. The maximum number of phrase lists used as a descriptor (feature) for a specific model to be 10 phrase lists.

just change their status from global to local

Answer (score 0):

The phrase lists limit recently changed (Nov 2019) from 10 to 500. Please review the [limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-boundaries#model-boundaries). If you find this isn't the case, please report it.

Comment: we have contacted MS support about this. Its currently on a hard limit of 10 for each LUIS model at the moment. They have plans for increasing the limit but does not have a definite timeline when. For now, what we did is we disected the related list entities to have its own LUIS model

Answer (score 0):

We have contacted customer support on this matter, and is currently a hard limit until further development happens. For now, the solution we did is we separated the LUIS models into different models instead of stacking it into the General.

It even made our LUIS models much better since its much clearer now what each LUIS model is all about (i.e Glossary, Human Resource, Customer Service, Admin, etc ...)

So I think this encounter even thought us something better, as separation of concern is a good approach.